# Properties on the tangent to a conic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the projective space $P(\mathbb{K}^3)$, $\Gamma$ is a projective conic, q is its quadratic form associated to a symmetric bilinear form $\phi$.

Let $d=P(H)$ be a projective line with $H$, a vector plane in $\mathbb{K}^3$. Let $\mathcal{B}=(a,b)$ a basis of $H$. Show the following equivalent properties:

$(1)$: $d$ is tangent to $\Gamma$.

$(2)$: $H$ is isotropic for $q$.

$(3)$: $q(a)q(b)=\phi(a,b)^2$

I have no idea how to prove the equivalence for (1) and (2). For (3), I tried computing the discriminant of the quadratic form to prove that $(3) \rightarrow (2)$, but could not make it any further.